# How can I write a regex that excludes values of a range?

Tags: java, regex

I have:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9[^lL]][a-zA-Z0-9[^oO]][a-zA-Z0-9[^kK]]
```

I'm just playing around with regex and want to create a regex that will accept any three characters of alphanumerical characters other than 'lok' in any combination of upper or lowercase. For some reason, what I have now accepts the input lok. Where is my error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're including `l`, `o`, and `k` in the `a-zA-Z`.  If you want to negate those letters with another character class you need to use `&&` (the [intersection](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/regular_expressions/character_classes.shtml)).

What you want is something like this:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9&&[^lL]][a-zA-Z0-9&&[^oO]][a-zA-Z0-9&&[^kK]]
```

However, depending on what you're trying to do, you could maybe accomplish your task with a [negative lookahead/lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).